# MSword regular express for Hindi Unicode

Tags: regex, ms-word, find

I have a large document in Devnagari (Hindi). It has words surrounded by brackets (). What I want to do is whatever inside (), make them bold using word's find/replace using formatting.

I tried to search what would fit it, but couldn't get to anything that is matching the text.

Sample text from the document is this:
`अन्‍वयार्थ―(स्‍वयंभुवा) जो स्‍वयंभू थे―दूसरे के उपदेश के बिना मोक्षमार्ग को जानकर तथा उस रूप आचरण कर अनन्‍तचतुष्‍टयस्‍वरूप हुए थे, (भूतहितेन) प्राणियों के लिये हितकारक थे, (समजसज्ञानविभूतिचक्षुषा) सम्‍यग्‍ज्ञान की विभूति रूप नेत्र से युक्‍त थे और (गुणौत्‍करै: करै:) स्‍वर्ग तथा मोक्ष की प्राप्ति में कारणभूत गुणों के समूह से युक्‍त वचनों के द्वारा (तम:) ज्ञानावरणादि कर्म रूप अज्ञान को (विधुन्‍वता) नष्‍अ करते हुए (येन) जो (भूतले) पृथ्‍वीतल पर (गुणौत्‍करै: करै:) अर्थ प्रकाशकत्‍व आदि गुणों से युक्‍त किरणों के द्वारा (तम:) अन्‍धकार को (विधुन्‍वता) नष्‍अ करते हुए (क्षपाकरेणैव) चन्‍द्रमा के समान (विराजितम्) सुशोभित होते थे ꠰꠰१꠰꠰`

Desired result from above text is **(स्‍वयंभुवा)**, **(भूतहितेन)**, **(समजसज्ञानविभूतिचक्षुषा)**...

Expressions I tried are:

```
(\()(.*?)(\))
(\(.*?\))
\(*.*\)*        // This one selects some text, but not the expected one. Rather it selects a large amount of text.
\(+.*\)+        // This one finds nothing
```

But these didn't work.

I tried ([\u0900-\u097F]) but this didn't give anything. 
Then I tried to search just for the hindi characters using [\u0900-\u097F]. What I saw is word is not selecting all characters of hindi. It's only selecting some of the characters though they are in the range as per the Unicode chart.

If you have any idea what could make it work or what is wrong I am giving, please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the following pattern in *Find What*:

```
\(*\)
```

And replace with `Font:Bold` by clicking inside the *Replace with* field, then clicking *Format* list box at the botton and selecting *Font...* > *Bold*.

Mind that `Use wildcards` option must be checked.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I spent an hour to figure this out but couldn't get it working. This solution worked.

Comment: I clicked the arrow button yesterday thinking it's the accept answer button bit apparently I was wrong. Just accepted the answer by clicking right button. Thanks.